# TSQL - Make Casting datetime as varchar not return friendly format

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, formatting, substring

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Person.Name AS PersonName,
    SUBSTRING(CAST(Person.BirthDate AS varchar(38)), 1, 2) AS CenteryBorn,
    Person.BirthDate AS CompleteDateTimeBorn
FROM Person
```

What I want is something like this, with `CenteryBorn` column having the first two digits of the datetime:

```
PersonName    CenteryBorn   CompleteDateTimeBorn

Fred          20            2000-03-16 00:00:00.000

Tim           19            1900-09-27 00:00:00.000

Jenny         19            1901-06-20 00:00:00.000
```

What I get however is this:

```
PersonName    CenteryBorn   CompleteDateTimeBorn

Fred          Ma            2000-03-16 00:00:00.000

Tim           Se            1900-09-27 00:00:00.000

Jenny         Ju            1901-06-20 00:00:00.000
```

The complete string representation seems to be end up being  `Mar 16 2000 12:00AM`.

Is there any way to `CAST` it as a string but in the default format rather than this friendly one?

Comment: Looks like two first char's of Month. substring from 8 for 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using:

```
YEAR(BirthDate)/1000
```

Comment: Thanks! But for whatever reason, this does not seem to work when I try to append it to another string, like : "YEAR(BirthDate)/1000"+Person.RestOfDate

Comment: CAST(YEAR(BirthDate)/100 as VARCHAR(100))

Answer (score 0):

you can use datepart function instead

```
substring(cast(datepart(y,person.birthdate) as varchar),1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT YEAR(Person.BirthDate) / 100 AS CenteryBorn`

Comment: Century would be `( Year( Person.BirthDate ) + 99 ) / 100`. The first century is years 1 through 100. 20th century would be 1901 through 2000.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I just gave what OP wanted in test data. Besides he  accepted incorrect answer at all :)